# fullcalendar failing jquery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Please forgive my lack of Js/jquery knowledge - hopefully this will be a simple question to answer.  I think I must be missing a script or something somewhere

So when the calendar renders

```
Calendar.prototype.initialRender = function () {
   var _this = this;
   var el = this.el;
   el.addClass('fc');  !fails here
```

The console tell me 'this' is the fullcalendar correctly

```
Calendar {loadingLevel: 0, ignoreUpdateViewSize: 0, freezeContentHeightDepth: 0, el: div#calendar, viewsByType: {…}, …}
constraints: Constraints {eventManager: EventManager, _calendar: Calendar}
currentDate: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Tue Jun 02 2020 17:03:57 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time), …}
defaultAllDayEventDuration: Duration {_isValid: true, _milliseconds: 0, _days: 1, _months: 0, _data: {…}, …}
defaultTimedEventDuration: Duration {_isValid: true, _milliseconds: 7200000, _days: 0, _months: 0, _data: {…}, …}
el: div#calendar
eventManager: EventManager {calendar: Calendar, stickySource: ArrayEventSource, otherSources: Array(0), jQuery1124013653863441134595: {…}}
freezeContentHeightDepth: 0
ignoreUpdateViewSize: 0
loadingLevel: 0
localeData: Locale {_fullCalendar_weekCalc: "local"}
optionsManager: OptionsManager {_watchers: {…}, _props: {…}, _calendar: Calendar, overrides: {…}, dynamicOverrides: {…}, …}
viewSpecManager: ViewSpecManager {optionsManager: OptionsManager, _calendar: Calendar, viewSpecCache: {…}}
viewsByType: {}
__proto__: Object
```

but shows 'el' is not a jquery object as needed in order for addClass to work

```
>el
div#calendar
```

And trying to call addClass fails

```
el.addClass('fc')
VM14452:1 Uncaught TypeError: el.addClass is not a function
    at eval (eval at Calendar.initialRender (fullcalendar.self-e9ae1b2c551f2f852ffbb704ecc1e434ee9bbc2cda72ea67fa3631cdace57650.js?body=1:9501), <anonymous>:1:4)
    at Calendar.initialRender (fullcalendar.self-e9ae1b2c551f2f852ffbb704ecc1e434ee9bbc2cda72ea67fa3631cdace57650.js?body=1:9501)
    at Calendar.render (fullcalendar.self-e9ae1b2c551f2f852ffbb704ecc1e434ee9bbc2cda72ea67fa3631cdace57650.js?body=1:9490)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (calendar.self-38bc6bd2dda3534fb8abc461acd3125490aec51a3e037753ae5812dac1925814.js?body=1:4)
    at Object.t.dispatch (turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js?body=1:6)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js?body=1:6)
    at r.pageLoaded (turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js?body=1:6)
    at turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js?body=1:6
```

Why isnt the el attribute a JQuery obect and why can it not call addClass.  If I do it manually it is fine

```
>$('div #calendar').addClass('fc')

jQuery.fn.init [div#calendar.fc, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "div #calendar"]
```

Comment: _"Why isnt the el attribute a JQuery object"_ ... I would guess because, as of fullCalendar 4 onwards, fullCalendar doesn't use jQuery internally. Unless you're using an older version here? You didn't mention the version. Anyway if you want to add a class to a native DOM element then just use `el.classList.add("fc");` - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList . If you really prefer to use jQuery, then just wrap `el` in a jQuery constructor: `$(el).addClass("fc");`

Answer (score -1):

It turns out the example on the full calendar page is wrong - I'm so impressed.

[initialise globals](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals)

The example supplies a DOM element to FullCalendar when you need to supply a jQuery element

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  -- **this needs to be calendarEl = $('#calendar')**

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ]});

  calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: No, this isn't true at all. All the demos you can find on the fullCalendar site (which mostly have source code links available) show that it works when you supply a DOM element. Here's a minimal demo I made using fullCalendar 4 to show trivially that it works: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/eYJYEjX . And here's another demo to show very simply that if you use a jQuery object instead, then it doesn't work - check the console message: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJMJjox

Comment: I don't know how you came to the conclusion in your answer. Can you provide a demo which reproduces this behaviour? I can only imagine you're doing something odd like mixing versions, messing with the fullCalendar source code, or using the wrong syntax for the version you are trying to work with. P.S. If you're working with version 3, which _does_ use jQuery, then you can find the documentation and examples here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3#toc . Note that the syntax and many other things are very different from v4.

Comment: Sorry - the problem is I have installed FullCalendar using the https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails gem and that gives version 3.9

Comment: ok well that page already shows examples of how to initialise the calendar, like `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/events.json'
});` for instance.  Beyond that, you should take a look at the introduction section of the v3 documentation, and/or study the source code of demos you find linked around the v3 docs. Start here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/intro

Comment: Of course the other alternative is to upgrade your fullCalendar version to the latest 4.x version (4.42 is the current one, as of this moment)